# how create JHipster application with Hazelcast

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jhipster, hazelcast

I want to create JHipster Application using Hazelcast. Can anyone give me some tips before starting?

Best regrds

Ismael

Comment: Looking for anything in particular?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://hazelcast.com/partner/jhipster/

You will find a link to a sample JHipster app that uses Hazelcast as Hibernate L2 cache, web session clustering etc.